# Instapaper read now and read later

Tags: instapaper

I can use the "Read Later" to put some article in Instapaper. And I can use the "Instapaper Text" bookmarklet to view the article directly (see http://www.instapaper.com/save).

But I want to do this at the same time; *read now* **and** save it to *read later*. Is that possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Instapaper's Mobilizer](http://mobilizer.instapaper.com/m) to view, like a "Read Now" from Readability.

After your URL opens, you can click "Save to Instapaper".

Answer (score 0):

They state on that page that it is not for read later:

> This Instapaper Text bookmarklet does not add the page to your Instapaper account.

Comment: Yes I know. Is there a workaround to do both? Like readability does.